# Chrome Devtools crashes on setState without a console.log before

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm developing a board game and to test both players I have this piece of code in my `componentDidMount`:

```
window.swap = () => {
    this.setState({
        self: rotate(this.state.game[0].players, this.state.game[0].players.indexOf(this.state.self))[1]
    })
}
```

This basically chooses the next player in the array of players and sets `self` to that so I can impersonate that player.

When I call `swap` the first time, it works fine, but when I call it again it it crashes the page. **However**, if I add a `console.log` before, like so:

```
window.swap = () => {
    console.log('what?')

    this.setState({
        self: rotate(this.state.game[0].players, this.state.game[0].players.indexOf(this.state.self))[1]
    })
}
```

it works fine every time. Even if I do a simple loop `for(let i=0; i<100; i++) swap()` it works fine, printing "what?" 100 times.

If I close DevTools and add something like this

```
setTimeout(() => {
    window.swap()
    window.swap()
}, 5000)
```

it works fine, with or without a `console.log` on `swap`. What?

EDIT:

Tested on:

- Chrome 70 (crash)
- Chrome Canary (72), Chromium, Firefox, Edge (ok)

So apparently this bug is fixed in next Chrome versions

Comment: When you say "crashes the page", do you mean you get an "aw, snap" message?

Comment: Yes, and DevTools gets disconnected

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with Chrome that is fixed in an upcoming version. If someone can point me to an issue page or something, I'm curious to what caused this.